# Make an hole at the center of a cylinder with a drill press

Tags: drill, hole

I have a drill press and I want to do an hole at the center of a cylinder but I don't know how to do...Can anyone help me?

Comment: At the center of the circular face or the curved side? What material?

Comment: At the center of the circular face.Plexiglass

Answer (score 2):

I'd create a channel out of wood blocks for the cylinder to lie in and pad it with a cloth. Something like this:

[image]

[Image source and more info](https://itp.nyu.edu/fab/drilling-into-a-pipe/)

Then I'd use an awl or nail set to create a divot in the surface of the acrylic. This will help prevent bit crawl, though a drill press usually takes care of that for you if you secure the work piece well.

Acrylic melts easily, so either drill fairly quickly or use a fluid bath for cooling.

Comment: Ok but how I could center this thing under the drill's tip?

Comment: Trial and error with base location and cylinder rotation. The article I just linked describes the use of a "center finder". I doubt you need that precision, though.

Comment: I thought to to a hole in a piece of wood with the drill press of the same diameter of the cylinder.Thwn without moving the piece of wood put the cylinder in that hole and in this way every hole you do is centered...What do you think about this idea?

Answer (score 0):

If you are centering on the circular face as noted in the post, you'd want to have a center finder tool, either one you've constructed yourself or a purchased model.

[image]

A quick internet search for "center finder tool" will give you more results to select. Scribe a line in one direction, turn the tool 90 degrees, scribe a line. Center punch and drill away.